# No module named 'matplotlib' when execute .py file to an app

Tags: python, pyinstaller

`enter code here`I am trying to execute my .py file to an app using pyinstaller.However, it fails to execute the script due to no module named 'matplotlib'. I have spent more than 2 days to fix it but have no hope for that. Has anybody a solution for my problem? Thank you very much.

The spec file looks like:

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas = []
binaries = []
hiddenimports = []
tmp_ret = collect_all('matplotlib')
datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['apptam.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\dell1\\Desktop\\app'],
             binaries=binaries,
             datas=datas,
             hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='apptam',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: You did pip install matplotlib already? Could you check in your python installation if you have that module in it?

Comment: I have already installed matplotlib. That's why I cannot understand the error

Comment: You could try to copy the module folder to the root of where your .py file is else what I could find in a quick google search is that you might want to add the --collect-all flag (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html?highlight=module#what-to-bundle-where-to-search)

Comment: Thank you. I follow your suggest and now another error happend. ImportError:Failed to import any qt binding. Could you give me some hints for that?

Comment: How does your pyinstaller spec file look? You don't need to copy any modules into your project.

Comment: the spec file :from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all
datas = []
binaries = []
hiddenimports = []
tmp_ret = collect_all('matplotlib')
datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['apptam.py'],pathex=['C:\\Users\\dell1\\Desktop\\app'],binaries=binaries,datas=datas,hiddenimports=hiddenimports, hookspath=[],runtime_hooks=[],excludes=[],win_no_prefer_redirects=False, win_private_assemblies=False,cipher=block_cipher,noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,cipher=block_cipher)

Comment: exe = EXE(pyz,a.scripts,a.binaries,a.zipfiles,a.datas,[],name='apptam',debug=False, bootloader_ignore_signals=False,strip=False,upx=True,upx_exclude=[],runtime_tmpdir=None,console=True )

Comment: Can you add it to your question's body? I am pretty sure some of the characters got removed, not easy to understand either.

Comment: Thanks, I already upload the spec file on the body of the question. please take a look and it is great if you can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

With python, execute the following command `help("modules")`. This will list all installed packages in your python, if you can't find `matplotlib` in there, this means that you're probably installed `matplotlib` in an other environment. You might also see if there is some syntax error in the import, and whether `matplotlib` version is compatible with your python version.

Comment: Actually, I run the script smoothly and the error only happened when I execute .py file to my app using pyinstaller. That's why I don't understand that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why this section is in the `spec` file -

```
tmp_ret = collect_all('matplotlib')
datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]
```

Unless you use a module that uses matplotlib (?)

I removed the entire section of the `collect_all` and PyInstaller collected everything properly without it, while collect_all caused the issue.

Try the command `pyinstaller -F apptam.py`. That will recreate your spec file without any additions and it should work.

---

**Edit:**

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas = []
binaries = []
hiddenimports = []
for required in ('matplotlib', 'PyQt5'):
    tmp_ret = collect_all(required)
    datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]
```

Make sure `Analysis` has the following, rather than `[]`:

```
binaries=binaries,
datas=datas,
hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
```

Comment: Because I follow the comment of @Uber and actually after using collect_all, the error "no module named 'matplotlib'"is solved. However, another error happened: ImportError:Failed to import any qt binding. I cannot solve it yet.

Comment: @Ng.Alina Do you have any PyQt modules installed? If you don't then try to install PyQt5 and try to compile with PyInstaller.

Comment: I have already PyQt5, but the error is still there. No solution founded yet

Comment: I don't have any issue with this, can you try generating a spec file using `pyinstaller -F apptam.py` and then changing the line that says `hiddenimports=[]` into `hiddenimports=['matplotlib']`. When you run your next pyinstaller command you should do it on the spec file: `pyinstaller apptam.spec`.

Comment: I follow your hint. But Another error happens: Failed to extract MSVCP140.dll. Decompression resulted in return code -1! I Don't understand why it is so hard to execute

Comment: @Ng.Alina What version is your PyInstaller and also what OS are you using? Personally, I have had bad experience with PyInstaller onefile compilation at work so we dropped the entire thing in favor of one dir and creating an installation file that also creates a shortcut. Can you also see if it also fails as one dir? `pyinstaller apptam.py` would create a folder, go into it and run the `apptam.exe` file.

Comment: yes, it also fails as one dir. Thank you for sharing your experiences. DO you have any recommendations for me? Which one should I use to execute the app instead of pyinstaller?

Comment: @Ng.Alina I am actually not familiar with the other options. I have edited my answer, try to add that code in the beginning of the spec file, it will collect all of `matplotlib` and `PyQt5` packages into your executable, hopefully that would solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But it still does not work. So crazy.

Comment: @Ng.Alina What is the problem that it shows now? Are you also running PyInstaller on the spec file, and not the `.py` file? `pyinstaller apptam.spec` and not `pyinstaller apptam.py`.

Comment: yes, I run on the spec file. the error shows: Failed to extract LIBPQ.dll:  Decompression resulted in return code -1!